# ¿Cómo obtener el tamaño de un objeto en Java?

Tags: java

Tengo el método siguiente, al cual se le pasa como parámetro una coordenada, ejemplos: Coordenada 2 dimensiones: coord --> (1, 2) Coordenada 3 dimensiones: coord --> (1, 2, 3) Coordenada 4 dimensiones: coord --> (1, 2, 3, 4)... Puede ser de cualquier dimensión.

```
public Set<Coordenada> obtenerAdyacentes(Coordenada **coord**)
```

Necesito saber el tamaño de la Coordenada que me pasan como parámetro, para saber si es de 2, 3, 4... dimensiones. Si es de 2 dimensiones tengo que hacer una cosa, si es de 3 dimensiones tengo que hacer otra cosa... Es decir, para cada dimensión tengo que hacer una cosa. Cómo puedo obtener el tamaño de esa **coord** de manera que pueda hacer:

```
if(coord == 2 dimensiones) 
// Bloque de código 
if(coord == 3 dimensiones) 
// Bloque de código 
if(coord == 4 dimensiones) 
// Bloque de código
```

Gracias!!

Comment: ¿La clase Coordenada es tuya? Añade el código en la pregunta

Comment: Lo más lógico sería que la clase `Coordenada` tuviese un método (`getSize()`) o propiedad (`size`) con el tamaño, así obtendrías el dato con `unaCoordenada.getSize()` o `unaCoordenada.size`....

Comment: Lo he resuelto finalmente y lo que buscaba era "instanceof", al haber empezado recientemente con Java, no sabía que existía para comprobar que la coordenada pertenecía a una clase. Gracias por vuestro tiempo y perdonad las molestias por la mala formulación de la pregunta